# How to use greensock with box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, gsap

I have been trying to use greensock with box2d for zoom in and out effect , now i use the below code ...

var t = TweenLite.to(level1WorldObj, 3, {scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, onComplete:scaleDown});

```
                function scaleDown()
                {
                        TweenLite.delayedCall(3, t.reverse);
                }
```

this zooms in over a period of 3 seconds and then zooms out ..

but when the zoom effect takes place the whole world shakes ...

What seems to be the problem is that i am working with box2d physics engine , now if i do the animation just on the movieclip it works well ....

But when i create a world and then put objects inside it , for example a bike rider and the focus is set on the rider  inside the world ...

When the world zooms it seems to vibrate every thing , however if used out side of physics world it works fine ...

Can you please guide me to some link here which suggests use of greensock with box2d , i searched but was unable to find one ....

Thanks in advance ....

Regards
Jin